# How to Set Access for a specific user to specific module in backend Joomla 2.5.4?

Tags: php, joomla, acl, joomla2.5

I have Joomla 2.5.4 in which I have two different ype of user groups, Now I want these both user to have specific access to specififc Modules/Components at Administrator(Backend)

Please guide me to find a ay to achive this.

Answer (score 1):

Just successfully completed these steps:

1. Created my own ACL from Users/Access Levels/Add New Access Level
2. Created my own User Groups from Users/Groups/Add New Group
3. Added a new Admin module that only allowed that Access level
4. Went to Extensions/Extension Manager and chose the Manage Tab
5. Selected an installed Admin Component
6. Clicked on Options, and selected the Permissions tab
7. Adjusted access permissions for the Group I had added

If I haven't fully understood your question, or this doesn't meet your need, perhaps an Admin User Plugin from the [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/backend-a-full-access-control) will accomplish what you need.

Comment: What you have done is the permitting a specific group to access "Module Manager" as a whole and restricting the other group using Module Manager Access Configuration, I am looking for access to specific group to specific extension/module